# Scales for simulation

Tags: multiscale-modeling

I am looking for literature on various scales (time, length, etc.) in atomistic or molecular simulation.

So far I have found bits and pieces here and there. E.g. [this is one of them](https://www.molbnl.it/node/116#:%7E:text=By%20definition%2C%20multiscale%20molecular%20modeling,to%20the%20different%20pertaining%20scale.). However, this is not a citable reference.

I am looking for a research article or a book chapter dedicated to this topic.

Can you supply me with one or more references?

Comment: Are not good the reference used there?  "More information on Multiscale molecular  modelling  can be found in: Scocchi et al., J. Phys. Chem. B, (2007), 111, 2143.; Toth R., Santese F., Pereira S.P., Romero-Nieto D., Pricl S., Fermeglia M., Posocco, Journal of Materials Chemistry, 22, 5398-5409 (2012) .;  Pereira S.P, Scocchi G., Toth R., Posocco P., Romero-Nieto D., Pricl S., Fermeglia M., Journal of Multiscale Modeling, 3:151-176 (2012) ."

Comment: @Camps, As I already wrote - *So far I have found bits and pieces here and there. ... ... ... I am looking for a research article or a book chapter dedicated to this topic.*

Comment: Take a look [here](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=Multiscale+Simulation+Methods+in+Molecular+Sciences+).

Comment: You might find this upcoming CECAM workshop interesting.  https://www.cecam.org/workshop-details/1119. As an aside - check out the references they list.

Answer (score 6):

## Multiscale Simulation Methods in Molecular Sciences

Edited by
Johannes Grotendorst
Norbert Attig
Stefan Blügel
Dominik Marx

Winter School, 2 - 6 March 2009
Forschungszentrum Jülich, Germany
Lecture Notes

Summary:

- Methodological Foundations
- Multiscale Simulation Methods for Solids and
  Material
- Multiscale Simulation Methods for Soft Matter and
  Biological Systems
- Numerical Methods and Parallel Computing

Download link: https://juser.fz-juelich.de/record/3737/files/nic-series-volume42.pdf

Answer (score 3):

I have found another reference in addition to what [Camps](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/9331/3990) has supplied.

- [Steinhauser, Martin Oliver. ***Computational multiscale modeling of fluids and solids.*** Berlin: Springer, 2017.](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-662-53224-9.pdf)

Chapter 1 (Introduction) of this book gives a moderately well coverage of time and length scales for modeling and simulation.

Comment: why would you select your answer which has one source, over someone elses who tried to help and gave several sources?

Comment: @B.Kelly, Okay, I deselected my answer. However, the answer to your question is - please read both resources, and you will realize it for yourself.

Comment: it is pretty solid, I may have to buy that one